# Textbox to dropdown onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox

Hello everyone I want to show a textbox on page load. This textbox will have the corresponding  department according to the user that is being modified.

For instance, when somebody wants to edit the information of a user that belongs to the human resources dept., the textbox will show "Human Resources". But if you want to modify that info, I want to be able to click on the textbox and it will behave as a dropdown list that displays all the available departments.

Also, If somebody wants to add a new department you could just type in the textbox the new one and save the user information.

How can I do this?

Hope I made myself clear, but if not, i'll be glad to answer your questions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use both dropdown and textbox.. Use CSS to overlap them. Then use jquery.. on textbox focus, hide textbox and show dropdown. and on drop down select change, revert the process.

Comment: For new department, put "Others" in dropdown and if they select it, allow the user to key in the textbox. if not dun let them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

I made a video tutorial on how to do this in asp.net a while back.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULHSqoDHP-U&list=UUgtKyNvllU9E6c2Mi8OtzCQ&index=6&feature=plcp